# Як буде "наслышан" українською?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, прикметники

На порталі [Сталі вирази](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua) знайшла:

> [**Наслышан**](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile.php?transfer=folders/en/naslyaan.html)
>
> **Много о ком, о чём наслышан** (*разг*. *устар*.).
> Багато чув про (за) кого, про (за) що.

Тобто українська не має відповідника слову *наслышан*? Можна казати лише *чув про…*?

Answer (score 8):

Відповідником до російського слова *наслышан (о ком/чем)* є українське слово **начутися** *(про кого/що)* або синонімічне слово **наслухатися** *(про кого/що)*.

Так, у СУМ-11 бачимо слово [начутися](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F):

> 1. Те саме, що наслу́хатися
>
> Вона-бо змалу начулася [про те], що вона красива (Кв.-Осн., II, 1956, 435).
>
> 2. Багато довідатися про кого-, що-небудь.
>
> Від Берника та від Гапія багато я начувся про Радянський Союз такого, що в душу запало (Мур., Бук. повість, 1959, 111);
>
> Багато начулася Маргіт про тих [радянських] лікарів та про їхнє рідкісне вміння рятувати людей (Гончар, Новели, 1954, 48).

Comment: @ Я помістив цитату, яка наведена в СУМі, бо ресурс https://books.google.com.ua не показує сторінок.... Тож хоч і багато прикладів звідти можна знайти (використовуючи звичайний ґуґлівський пошуковик), але просто авторства і назви книги, мабуть, мало було б.

Comment: Чому ж, мені здається, назви й імені автора цілком достатньо (особливо, якщо Ви додаєте інтернет-посилання). Он СУМ-20 взагалі лише ім'я автора вказує. Але, звісно, та цитата, що Ви додали, теж цілком прийнятна. (Тільки от що у відповіді не згадується _наслухатися_ — але то, звісно, як Вам зручніше.)

Comment: Начувся - це зросійщення у значенні "маю чутки". Всі приклади також з літератури розквіту радянського періоду. Українці кажуть: "знаю", "мені відома ця інформація", "чув про це багато від кого", "повідомлений".

Comment: "Наслухався" можна сказати про сусідські лайки. Але не про інформацію.

Answer (score 3):

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник](//r2u.org.ua/html/announcement.html) раде таке:

> **Наслышанный**, [**наслышан**](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on) — наслуханий.
>
> > — *Я наслуханий і набачений різних ситуацій у так званому політичному бомонд*… (Сергій Добржанський).

Якшчо лякає *народний*, то ось [словник української мови в 20 книгах](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85):

> [**Наслу́ханий**](//sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=178796&page=1805), а, е, *розм*.
>
> 2. *у знач. прикм*. Який наслу́хався багато чого-небудь.
>
>    > — *Вона, бідна, так була наслухана, що .. щодня когось знімали, що й не подумала над тим, що я сказав* (В. Кучер); *От кіммерійці здумали прощатись, наслухані про скіфську силу й лють* (Л. Костенко); — *Пане адмірале, я наслуханий про вашу геніальну книгу!* (Г. Тарасюк).

Теж розмовне, однак також з прикладами від зразкових письменників.

---

<sub>Від себе.</sub>

- Радю також звернути на запитання [«Слухаєш, але не чуєш, чи чуєш, але не слухаєш?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/641/585).
- Українській відомо про [короткі форми](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2) прикметників чоловічого роду. Тут прикметник без хитрошчів, тому якшчо таки конче потрїбно утворити, то просто прибираємо **-ий**: *наслухан*.

Answer (score -1):

Можна сказати так: "чув (про) таке/це", "чули про Вас", "говорили люди" тощо.

Comment: Знов-таки, як і [тут](/a/6884), Ви пропонуєте дуже доречні варіанти. Цього разу нема сумнівів в їхній коректності (того разу слово було несловникове). Але однаково відповідь варто було б трішки розширити.

Comment: Друзі, якщо чесно, давно я не бачив такої недоброзичливої спільноти, як у вас. Мова - це не словники, які написали дядьки в окулярах, які прожили все життя в Києві і ніколи не бачили корови, мова жива, вона усюди, і те, що є в книзі, має віддзеркалювати те, що є в житті. Чому не можна дати посилання "почув на Закарпатті", або "так каже моя бабуся"? Ось чому я покинув університет: бо в ньому не заохочують до ініціативи, а зовсім навпаки, муштрують копірайтерів. На цій мінорній ноті покидаю вашу педантичну спільноту, яка так старанно хоче послужити Україні, що аж відлякує від себе людей.

Comment: @AlecOwski, чесно кажучи, я з Вами згоден — нам не завадило би додати відкритості/емпатії. Але тон спільноти — це не незмінна річ, а просто середнє арифметичне поглядів найактивніших учасників. Приєднуйтеся — і, можливо, Ви зможете змінити його на краще.